# Load saved data from Sqlite database in Combox and use SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: vb.net

I have a Combobox with the name `Afzender` , in Formload i load a lot of items from a Sqlite database into the Combobox . No problem there .

When i select a name from the Combobox it gets items from the database with that selected name with `SelectedIndexChanged` and fill in some textboxs. Works fine.

The question , when i save the selected `Naam` and load it again the `Naam` is in the `Afzender` but how do i make the Combox use the `SelectedIndexChanged` .

Don't want to save the Textboxes also , only the selected `Naam`.

Tyred to use `Afzender.Validating`, or do i need to use another ?

```
 Private Sub Afzender_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Afzender.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCeCommand("Select Adres, Postcode, Plaats, Land FROM Ontvanger Where Naam = @Naam", con2)

        If con2.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con2.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Naam", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Afzender.Text
        Dim sdr As SqlCeDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While sdr.Read = True
            Afzenderadres.Text = sdr.Item("Adres")
            Afzenderpostcode.Text = sdr.Item("Postcode")
            Afzenderplaats.Text = sdr.Item("Plaats")
            Afzenderland.Text = sdr.Item("Land")

        End While
        sdr.Close()
        con2.Close()
        Afzenderplaats.Text = Afzenderpostcode.Text & " " & Afzenderplaats.Text
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it mean: *when i save the selected Naam and load it again*? Save it where / when? There's nothing related to this in the question -- If you need to run the code you have in `SelectedIndexChanged`, then just move that code to its own method and call that method when needed

Comment: This code shows nothing related to a `ComboBox`. Please show the **relevant** code.

Comment: Never use an empty try-catch.  Put those disposable objects into using-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to execute the assignment of the Afzender texboxes that are inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` everytime you load your Form, not only when you change the SelectedIndex of the ComboBox.

You can achieve this by moving the code to another function and then call it whenever you need it, in this example you call it at `Form1_Load`, so every time you start the application, and also every time `Afzender_SelectedIndexChanged` is fired.

```
Public Class Form1

    Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ReloadAfzenderInformation()
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Afzender_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Afzender.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            ReloadAfzenderInformation()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReloadAfzenderInformation()
        cmd = New SqlCeCommand("Select Adres, Postcode, Plaats, Land FROM Ontvanger Where Naam = @Naam", con2)

        If con2.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con2.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Naam", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Afzender.Text
        Dim sdr As SqlCeDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While sdr.Read = True
            Afzenderadres.Text = sdr.Item("Adres")
            Afzenderpostcode.Text = sdr.Item("Postcode")
            Afzenderplaats.Text = sdr.Item("Plaats")
            Afzenderland.Text = sdr.Item("Land")

        End While
        sdr.Close()
        con2.Close()
        Afzenderplaats.Text = Afzenderpostcode.Text & " " & Afzenderplaats.Text
    End Sub

End Class
```